# how to join where primary key has both integer and string value

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables as shown in the image. I need to join two tables using the id from table 1 and id_number from table 2 as primary key. The primary key of Table 1 has both integer and string value.

When I use `LEFT JOIN`, I am getting the records related to the integer only. I would like to get the output for both integer and string as shown in the output table. There are million of rows in both Table 1 and Table 2. Can anyone assist please. I am using google bigquery. My code is as follows:

```
select t1.* ,t2.District,t2.Division,t2.Country 
from t1 
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want rows from both tables, so this suggests a `full join`:

```
select id, t1.name, t1.postition, t1.department, t1.salary, t2.district, t2.division, t2.country
from t1
full join t2 using(id)
```

This can be shortened with handy `except` extension:

```
select id, t1.* except(id), t2.* except(id)
from t1
full join t2 using(id)
```

Comment: @ GMB, when i use full join it takes indefinite time to run.

Comment: If you need to keep the the row which the key is not present in both tables, you need to use full join. If your data is too large to be processed by a full join you should consider changing your data model